# Why substitute expression for $x$ back into $f$ to prove surjectivity?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Given: function, $f: A {\to} B$, in terms of a formula. 
 
Goal:  Want to show $f$ is surjective. 
 
Question: When you use the method where you solve the eqn $y = f(x)$ for $x$, why do some texts have an additional step where you have to substitute the expression for $x$ back into $f$ and show you get $y$? It seems to me that as long as you can put any value of $B$ into the expression for $y$ (which you can determine by observation) and the resulting $x$ value is always in the domain of $f$, this should suffice. If you solved the original equation for $x$ correctly, it would seem obvious that you should get $y$ back. I don't see what this extra step gets you.

Comment: perhaps you could get some extra roots while solving? (e.g. when you raise both parts of an equation into an even power this can happen, and you can get roots which are in the domain of the function, but they don't satisfy the original equation...)

Comment: To show that $f$ is surjective, one needs to show that for all $y$ there exists an $x$ with $f(x)=y$. Hence the preferred method is to exhibit some $x$ (depending on $y$) and then to show that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Many times when you solve an equation you use steps that are $\Rightarrow$, so at the end you are not guaranteed the found solutions will satisfy your original equation. But if you were working using $\Leftrightarrow$ then you would be fine.

Comment: For instance $-1 =\sqrt x \Rightarrow 1^2= (\sqrt x)^2 \Rightarrow 1=x$ But the first does not have solution and the last has. So you solved for $-1$ with $f(x)= \sqrt x$. We ended with the solution $1$ which it did not satisfy your equation.

Comment: @clark   I see. So in your example if we let f be the function mapping the reals into the reals such that f:x->x^2, then setting y = sqrt(x) implies x = y^2. Even though any y can be put into the last relation, when you resubstitute x=y^2 into f, you get sqrt(y) which is equal to y iff y is non-negative.  Thanks!